# Pointer to single bytes of vector of doubles

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, char

I have vector of doubles and I need to have pointer with access to each single byte (probably char *ptr).
Can you tell me how to assign pointer to char to vector, so I can read values of each byte?

C++

Comment: Perhaps std::vector<char*> is what you need. Disintegrate the double in bits and store each of those bits in a char array.

Comment: You can use `std::vector::data` and `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<T>` has a method: T * data(),
which returns a pointer to the vector's data.

In a vector of doubles, `data()` will return a `double*`.

You can then use `reinterpret_cast` to cast the pointer to a single byte pointer (e.g. unsigned char pointer).

```
std::vector<double> a;
double * pData = a.data();
unsigned char * pDataBytes = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pData);
```

However - you should know exactly what you are doing. Using reinterpret_cast can cause many problems and UB.

**UPDATE**:

Based on the comments, I would like to correct that using reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*> by itself is not UB. I just meant that once you start to mess with the byte representation of objects which have other kinds of content, you have to know exactly what you are doing, as it is easy to do things that lead to UB.

Comment: reinterpreting as `unsigned char` is always ok. Problems may arise when casting to arbitrary types, but not with `unsigned char`, `char` or `std::byte`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number While reinterpreting as those types is not UB, it's "OK" only in some cases. In particular, the contents of the reinterpreted bytes may differ between systems (mainly due to endianness, but theoretically also due to floating point representation).

Comment: @eerorika right. I just think the last sentence is a little misleading. It isnt the reinterpret_cast specifically that can cause many problems or UB here. It is looking at the byte representation of the doubles, and thats just what OP is asking for. That would be the same without reinterpret_cast (eg via memcpy)

Comment: Updated the answer based on the comments.